# Difference between Hibernate download options?

Tags: java, hibernate

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/

Above I have a link to the Hibernate download page as you can see, at least today the top folder is:

`4.1.7-Final`

Above that though it says download latest version:

`hibernate-search-4.1.1.Final-dist.zip (31.0 MB)`

My questions are:

1. Which file should I download?
2. Why does the latest version have a lower number then the version at
   the top of the list.
3. Is the latest download a stable build with `4.1.7` been a test
   version?
4. What is the meaning of hibernate-search as the title?
5. Why are some files called final and others called:

   - `Alpha`
   - `Beta`
   - `CR1-5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at: [Software Release life cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle).

*CR* - Stands for Candidate for Release; more commonly known as:
*RC* - Release Candidate

The final version is the one you should really be using for any production development.

Also, instead of downloading dependencies manually, you may want to consider using Maven for dependency management.

Comment: Out of the 2 options with Final should I pick hibernate-search-4.1.1.Final-dist.zip (31.0 MB) as opposed to 4.1.7-Final?

Comment: Well as you can guess 4.1.7 is newer than 4.1.1 - and as such will have some more bug fixes. The only reason why you may go with an older version are: compatability issues, new critical bug, upgrade would require unjustifiable regression testing, etc..